# where does df.cache() is stored is this store on driver memory or executor memory

Tags: apache-spark, caching, pyspark

> Blockquote

if it store executor level then it should through out of memory error in case of data frame size more then executor memory

Answer (score 0):

It is stored at the executor(s). If you choose the storage level as StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK or StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER then it will store the data in disk when memory is low.

Comment: So if user choose MEMORY_ONLY then it will through an error in case of overhead of executor memory Am i correct?

Comment: No, it will cache tha data which could be cached and rest will not cache so in this point there is no use of cache

Comment: I think MEMORY_ONLY will crash if it can't store all data in memory.

Comment: 's no it will not, it will calculate rest data on run time, there is no any crash